# I want to use my Robotframework to upload file but my fileupload fill has no ID

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, selenium2library

I want to upload my picture but my upload fill has no id because it's angular and my programer refuse to write some id for me .

The question is how can i locate my robot to fill for upload file ??
because i try to input some text and it is not working in anyway 
(sry for my bad eng skill this is my first time to ask something like this)

[This is my html tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtp2c.png)

```
    <input _ngcontent-yhb-c11 style="display: none;" type="file">
```

[This is my robot code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEHqw.png)

```
Right Input test
Location Should Be  https://app.smartfinder.asia/operation/core/right/right-user-signup
Input Text    name=UserCode    ${Email}
Click Element    xpath=//*[contains(text(),'Adds')]
Click Element   xpath=//*[@class='signup-picture']
Choose File  xpath =//input[_ngcontent-ctj-c11]  C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\CabinetRB\\Reset passcode.PNG
```

I expect to upload my file but there is nothing happend
and hope u guy will understand what i wanna say 
 i'm new with this tool thx for the help

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly. no one will write code from the images to help you, add that code as part of question as code, its like help me, help you !!

Comment: @Dev . I edit what u say Dev thx for notice my question

Comment: The `Choose File` would work if you correctly identify the input of type='file'. But you should not activate the browser file selector. You have to use xpath to locate the input based on an identifiable parent.

Comment: @Helio so i edit by what u say but it didn't  work  it say  'Element with locator 'xpath =//input[_ngcontent-ctj-c11]' not found.' what should i do now sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found how to resolve that solution i identify by using style="display: none;" so thx for helping  Helio

```
Choose File  xpath =//input[@style='display: none;']  C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\CabinetRB\\Reset passcode.PNG
```